# I confused with the error when i wrote the code like short a = 1;a=a (short)1;

Tags: java, classcastexception, short

Today when i wrote some java codes it always gives me tips of error in red colors.
Flowing is the code:

```
short a = 1;a=a + (short)1;
```

I guess it must be the ClassCastException,but i am not able to understand the reason,could you do me a favor?Thanks!

Comment: So your IDE gives you an error and you want us to guess what error is? Your IDE says it!!

Comment: Yes!I want to know the deep reason in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can better try with:

```
a= (short)1;
```

instead of

```
a=a (short)1;
```

[ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) is:-

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an instance.

Although in your code it is not making sense how you receive the **ClassCastException** even after if we change as I suggested.

As in your code you have taken `a` as `short` and initialized it with value `1`. Now later why you want to cast the value `a`  as `short` as it is already `short`?

Example of ClassCastException could be like this:-

```
Object i = Integer.valueOf(1);
String s = (String)i;
```

Answer (score 0):

`a=a (short)1;` is wrong syntax.

The correct syntax would be

```
a= (short)1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know write like that is wrong syntax,but i just want to know the reason.Could you help me?